# Border of HTML fieldset overlaps legend

Tags: html, css

So I have an HTML fieldset and legend, and had issues with the `background-color` in the fieldset spilling outside of the borders in IE7. I was able to resolve the issue by using negative margins, like so:

```
fieldset {
    background-color:#E6E2D7;
    padding-top:5px;
    position:relative;
}

fieldset legend {
    position: absolute;
    top: -0.6em;
    left: 0.5em;
}
```

Now the border of the fieldset crosses over the legend in IE8+/Firefox/Chrome, but looks fine in IE7.

Is this a known issue and if so, is there a workaround?

Below is a link to a screenshot of the issue:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This one is hard to answer without seeing the problem in action. Could you create a jsfiddle demonstrating it? I have started on one here: http://jsfiddle.net/9r9ZS/

Comment: The comment below answered my question, thanks.

Comment: if you'd like to keep the same position for the legend, then just apply backgroud color to it, This would overlay the fieldset border.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have an IE7 specific css class by adding * + html before its definition

Example:

```
/* IE7 specific css*/
* + html fieldset legend {
    position: absolute;
    top: -0.6em;
    left: 0.5em;
}

/* all other browsers*/
fieldset legend {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: @user609926 Can you click 'This answer is useful', that way daolaf will get some points as well